# Variables declared in header not available in other includes

Tags: php, variables

I have a var set in my header.php file:

```
$myBool = false;
```

and in page.php, I try to echo it:

```
echo $myBool;
```

But the variable is never set.
This doesn't help either:

```
global $myBool;
echo $myBool;
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Note: I'm using a custom theme based on the blank theme ( http://digwp.com/2010/02/blank-wordpress-theme/ ) but the same behaviour is evident when using twentyten / eleven so the theme seems to have nothing to do with this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to globalize it before you set the value, so in your header.php

```
global $myBool;
$myBool = false;
```

and then in your page.php

```
global $myBool;
echo $myBool;
```

just make sure you page.php includes the header.php file either directly or by calling `get_header();`

Comment: this worked out, thanks. I didn't realise initialising the var with global was required... do you have a reference article for that by any chance?

Comment: This is a nice write up http://www.thewebsqueeze.com/web-design-tutorials/writing-functions-in-php-global-variable.html